# Google Analytics subdirectory filter not working

Tags: google-analytics

I've created a Google Analytics view to track all visits to www.example.com/wordpress/*

This is the filter:

[image]

However, this view shows no traffic after a week.

If I look at the default view that doesn't have this filter, there are visits to the /wordpress/ subdirectory included in the stats.

What is wrong with my filter please?

Thanks, Steve

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programing related.  may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you other filters for that view?

Comment: @MichelePisani, no, no other filters.

Comment: Try to set "contains" instead of "equal to".

Comment: Thanks @MichelePisani, no difference, no data is collected.

Comment: Is it a view created for user-id or is it a normal view?

Comment: It says: `User-ID Reports: Disabled`, @MichelePisani.

Comment: Ok, I added an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on comments on the main post, especially where you say *It says: User-ID Reports: Disabled*, I think the problem is that you are using a User-ID view.

So create a new view from the dedicated button '+ Create View':

[image]

And then apply the filter you have already created to this new view.

Note: a new views may need a few time to work properly so if you don't see the data immediately, wait from a few minutes to a few hours.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I remember when creating the view the first time I did select `Show User-ID Reports`. This time I didn't select it, and Real Time Reporting sees my visit. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent, if the problem is solved mark the answer as correct, please, and let me know if I deserved the Bounties :)

Comment: The View has not received any traffic since my own visit. However, nor has the main site's View for some reason. Give me a few days please.

Comment: In this case either the code has been removed from the page or there is an error in page that invalidates it.

Comment: Traffic numbers are back to normal, and the View is recording data. Cheers.

Comment: Well! Thanks for the feedback and the bounties. I wish you a good job and a good continuation :)